# React: How to plot API response in highchart

Tags: json, reactjs, highcharts, axios

Hi I have this reacr/flask app that when you put a keyword it sends it to flask check some data and then sents it back to react as the following json response:

[image]

I want to be able to plot these values using 'highcharts-react-official' package.

As of now im able to see my response on the console but nothing on the chart. I changed the dates into that timestamps but not sure if it's better or I should be using datetime, I can change it back if necessary.

My code is the following:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import Highcharts from 'highcharts'
import HighchartsReact from 'highcharts-react-official'


class Keyword extends Component {

  state = {
    kws :[]
  }


keyword = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    axios.post("/trends",{search_keyword: document.getElementById("keywords").value})
    .then((res) => {
    

      const data = res.data

      const keyword = data.data
  
      console.log("first index", keyword[1])


       this.setState({kws: keyword})
      

    }
    )}



  render() {

    const {kws =[]} = this.state

    const options = {
  title: {
    text: 'My chart'
  },
  xAxis: {
    type: 'datetime'
  },
  series: [{
    data: kws
  }]
}

    return (


<HighchartsReact
    highcharts={Highcharts}
    options={options}
  />
);
  }
}
```

Im looking to plot something like this:

[image]

**Update:** I Have updated the JSON response to be like this:

[image]

Would this be a better structure for plotting? If so what do I do to plot each keyword and its values like the graph above?

UPDATE2: I have updated my Json file
[image]

Comment: I would say the data for the series is not the correct format that the chart can understand... at a quick glance you are giving the data an array of objects.

Your data has timestapms as keys as well, you might want to manipulate that.

Have you looked through the HighCharts docs?
https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-react#optimal-way-to-update

Comment: What would be the correct way? I can transpose the JSON response so it's the other way. Would that be better?

Comment: Well you have price action over time... and need to give the series as an array of numerals 
        series: [
          { data: [1, 2, 3] }
        ],

Comment: This gives an excellent example of how the data looks for the series... and yours does not match this... https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-4ded5d?file=index.js

Comment: I see. So having the data like this would work? https://imgur.com/a/3dP09Du??

Comment: I have updated my question with the new api response

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to parse your data into the proper format which Highcharts will be able to recognize. Base on your screen from an update it should be something like below:

```
series: [{
  name: 'ps2',
  data: [
    [1579996800, 67],
    [1580601600, 70],
    [1581206400, 68],
    [1581811200, 72],
    etc...
  ]
}, {
  name: 'ps2 emulator',
  data: [
    [1579996800, 59],
    [1580601600, 69],
    [1581206400, 71],
    [1581811200, 63],
    etc...
  ]
}]
```

Comment: I see, So I'm building the JSON response on python. To do this should I make the keyword( ps2, ps2 emulator)  the index of the DF? Also when transforming the df into json im using to_json(orient="table") should I use jsonify? Maybe I should ask a different question :D But this is super helpful and sends me the right direction

Comment: @Sundios sorry, I don't know python. I just showed how the series object should look like. More: https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/series

Comment: Hi Sebastian, thanks for your help. I have updated the JSON response. Would that be a correct response for high chart to plot the results? or DateTime has to be like you showed like DateTime, value instead of "datetime": value?

Comment: @Sundios could you do a copy/paste of this JSON response to some online editor that I could test?

Comment: Thank you for your help Sebastian. Here is the example. https://jsfiddle.net/qLzmoup3/

Comment: Nope, it doesn't look like a correct format. Once again: https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/series the data could be: 1. Array of y values: `[1, 2, 3]`; 2. Array of arrays: `[ [x, y], [x, y], [x, y], ... ]` 3. Array of objects: `[ {x : x value, y: y value}, {x : x value, y: y value}, ...]`. Now your JSON doesn't remind any of it. Of course, it is possible to parse this response to the required format, but it requires a lot of work and I think that it should be done on the backend side if it is possible.

Comment: Got it. Yes, I will make the response in the backend to send something like [x, y], [x, y], [x, y]. Thanks so much for your help!